# Case of convex function

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces

I have a following problem.

a) Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be convex set and $f\colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ convex function.
Show that a set $f^{-1}(-\infty, a)$ is convex for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

b) find an example, where $f^{-1}(0, \infty)$ is **not** convex.

I have proven the first half, but I struggle to find such example.

I was thinking using some norm, since triangular inequality is one of the properties and I could use those inequality in definition of convex function...

Can anyone puts some light on this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to b):

Let $A=\mathbb{R}^n, f(x)=|x|-1$. Then:

1.$\forall\lambda\in[0,1]$

$$\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)=\lambda|x|+(1-\lambda)|y|-1\geq|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y|-1=f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)$$
so $f$ is convex.

2.$f^{-1}(0,\infty)=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{D}^n(1)$ is not convex.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{D}^n (1)$ ?

Comment: @markich: $\mathbb{D}^n(1)=\{x||x|\leq1\}$, the unit disc.

Comment: All clear now, thanks Alfred Chern!